# asp.net Is it possible to create a dropdownlist like the one in ms-word fontsize

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery

I am creating an application to save the font name, size and color for the entered text to the database. For Color and name i am displaying it from the system font and color.

Problem: For the font size i want to make the dropdownlist to act as dropdownlist used for fontsize in ms-word. 1. We can select size already exist in the list and also  to allow the user to enter the values they need.

Is it possible or is there any other good idea for this?

Geetha.

Answer (score 0):

ckeditor have something similar

http://ckeditor.com/demo

I think the idea is to create a "menou" base on a **ul-li** set, and inside the **li** you place the fonts as you like

here is a menu example for jQuery.
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for rich text editor .. I think in Ajax we are having a tool..

Check for this

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HTMLEditor.aspx

You can also have a simple one

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php