# how can i make combobox in a datagridview cell editable?

Tags: gridview, c#-3.0, combobox

i have a combo box in a data grid view cell.i need to make it editable.
how can I do so.

Comment: Please post your code. editable means what you want to do with the combobox. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: while the combobox in the gridview having a drop down list,the user can be able to add his own text or can be able to edit the selected text from the drop down list.

Comment: Post some code so we understand your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

HI,

Edited:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/EditableDropdown_aspx.aspx
   http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/622248-possible-create-editable-drop-down-list-using-asp-net

[asp.net Is it possible to create a dropdownlist like the one in ms-word fontsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499695/asp-net-is-it-possible-to-create-a-dropdownlist-like-the-one-in-ms-word-fontsize)

i dont think so it is possible to place a textbox inside the dropdownlist. I also tried the same process.

Geetha